# property or indexer 'WebApplication1.Default.Credentials' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code where I'm trying to set property like below.

```
protected ICredentials Credentials
{
    get
    {
        if (Credentials == null)
        {
            Credentials = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ApplicationId) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)
                ? CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
                : new NetworkCredential(ApplicationId, Password);
        }
        return Credentials;
    }
}
```

It is giving error like below.

[image]

"ICredentials" is an "Interface" from "System.Net". [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icredentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

Any idea how to fix it?

I checked following threads but they are not of any use.

[Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309770/property-or-indexer-cannot-be-assigned-to-it-is-read-only)

[Property or indexer cannot be assigned to :: string2[i] = sting1[i]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244999/property-or-indexer-cannot-be-assigned-to-string2i-sting1i)

[cannot be assigned to -- it is read only - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920784/cannot-be-assigned-to-it-is-read-only-c-sharp)

["cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" error on ConditionExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605180/cannot-be-assigned-to-it-is-read-only-error-on-conditionexpression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the property itself inside the property implementation, which is wrong on its own. Besides, `Proxy` does not have a setter, so you cannot set it, and that is exactly what the error message is saying.

What you are probably up to can be done with a private field though:

```
private IWebProxy _proxy;
protected IWebProxy Proxy
{
    get
    {
        if (_proxy == null)
        {
            _proxy = HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            _proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        }
        return _proxy;
    }
}
```